# Problems using Drools and Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, drools

When i modified a rule in .drl, modified don't take effect. Is it possible to modified *(i.e. hot deploy)* a rule *(.drl)* in drools without restarting the server *(tomcat)*? How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is - there are a few ways - but the first question is how you are loading the rules in the first place - are you loading them from the classpath? or somewhere on disk? There is a KnowledgeAgent (and RuleAgent) class that can load it from a variety of sources, and detect changes and apply them for you automatically when you change a drl file.

Comment: I create a knowledgeBase with spring and then i create a session and fire rules just when i need to be executed. I think that the problem with KnowledgeAgent is that it's continuesly scanning directories, is it performance? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The scanning shouldn't normally be an issue. one day (java 7?) that can go away as true file notifications are possible.